# AVG() MySQL giving wrong answer in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT avg(costPrice) as avgCP from table1 where active=1;
```

This is the sql command to calculate average a column. This is giving the correct answer when I run the command using SQL in phpmyadmin.

But when I run this via PHP it returns wrong answer. Even when there are 2 rows with one active as 0 and one active as 1. It gives me average of both. why so?

Comment: Show us your php code

Comment: Please share your sql query?

Comment: The query is in his question, the php code perhaps could point to why.

Comment: Please share your  code and sql query.